# Cambiar la interfaz de administrador de Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Deseo acceder a mi interfaz de administración personalizada en Django y desactivar el admin que trae por defecto

1. Tengo mi propio formulario personalizado para hacer login.
2. Quisiera que al momento de hacer login, acceda a mi propio sitio de administración personalizado.
3. No quiero utilizar el que trae Django.
4. Ya tengo la configuración del login solo que ahora estoy algo perdido para poner mi propio sitio de administración.
5. Desactivar el admin de django y prácticamente poner el index_admin.html

Mis archivos están así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**rbm/rbm/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from usuarios import urls as usuarios_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='acceder'),
    url(r'^usuarios/', include(usuarios_urls)),
    url(r'^', auth_views.login,{'template_name': 'usuarios/login.html'}),

]
```

**rbm/rbm/usuarios/templates/login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
    <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Aceder a RBM-LAPS</title>
</head>
<body class="login-fond">

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
        please login with an account that has access.</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="row login-top">
      <div class="col offset-l4 l4 s12">
        <div class="card white z-depth-3">
          <div class="card-login card-title login-color white-text">
              <h3>INICIAR SECIÓN</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
              <div class="row">
                <form class="col s12" method="post" action='{template_name="bla/nl"}, name='login' '>
                {% csrf_token %}

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>                    
                      {{ form.username }}
                      <label for='id_usuario'>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
                      {{ form.password }}
                      <label for="id_password">{{ form.password.label_tag }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <button class="btn btn-login waves-effect waves-purple teal accent-4" type="submit" value="login" > 
                            Aceder
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/materialize.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un error o problema en específico? Asegúrate de modificar tu pregunta para hacerla específica.

Comment: El admin de Django es simplemente una aplicación más del proyecto, si quieres usar tu propio admin simplemente no uses el de Django e incluye el tuyo propio

Comment: Gracias César... Entonces creo una app más para hacer mi propio admin...

Answer (score 1):

Voy a asumir q quieres hacer una propia admin tuya desde 0 y no personalizar o extender la propia de Django.
Primero q nada si no quieres usar la app de admin de Django la puedes quitar o comentar en la lista de aplicaciones instaladas INSTALLED_APPS en el fichero settings.py:

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',

    # incluyes tu app de admin
    'miadmin',

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

y por supuesto quitarla de las urls de tu sitio e incluir las de tu propia administración:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
# from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # incluyes las urls de tu propia admin
    url(r'^admin/', include('miadmin.urls')),
]
```

espero q te ayude la respuesta

saludos

Answer (score -1):

Creo que puedes solucionarlo comentando esta linea

```
//url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

en el archivo `urls.py`